# How to dynamically load telerik datepicker using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, telerik-mvc

how to load telerik datepicker dyanlically.

i am constructing a div tag with, html textbox and thought of appending telerik datepicker, can this be done, and can someone explain me the way to do it.

```
<div id="mainDiv"> 
str +='<div class="Subdiv" id='; 
str += data.id + ' rel="' + relData + '"><br/>Date Question<br/><label>'; 
str += data.Question + "<br/><input type='textbox' id='Date'/></br></br>"; 
str += "<input type='button' value='Submit' onclick='Submitdate(\"" + data.previousdate+"\",\"" + data.id+ "\",\"" + data.changetype+ "\")'/>"; } $('#Date').appendTo(document.body).tDatePicker(); 
str += '</label></div>'; $('#mainDiv').append(str);
```

i am getting an error `$('#Date').appendTo(document.body).tDatePicker();` is not a function.

Comment: Please edit your original question by posting the code inside the question as an update

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

Register datepicker client side library:

```
$(Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().DefaultGroup(group => group.Add("telerik.common.js").Add("telerik.datepicker.js")))
```

Create an input element on your form:

```
<input id="DatePickerInput" />
```

Then add the following javascript somewhere on the page:

```
$('#DatePickerInput').appendTo(document.body);
$('#DatePickerInput').tDatePicker();
```

or

```
$('#DatePickerInput').appendTo(document.body).tDatePicker();
```

To set a date value:

```
$('#DatePickerInput').val('5/29/2012');   //Date format may vary, you'll need to adjust it!
```

Good luck!

Comment: you also need to add "telerik.calendar.min.js"

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
var datePicker = $("<input>", { id: "Date", value: "1/1/2013"})
                                                      .appendTo(document.body);
datePicker.tDatePicker();
```

That should work!